# Existence of similar data inside flower bracket- python

Tags: python

I have an excel sheet entry having multiple strings encompassing characters like "{,-,}," in every row.
I am parsing through each of the string and checking for entries of "{"

My string looks like below:

```
string1="stack-{data}-XYZ-ABC-DEF-
{data}-DAB24-GOOD45-XYA-BYCS-{data}-"
```

I have the above string1 which has few data inside "{ }". I want to parse through the string and check if the data inside the "{ }" are same or not.

I am new to python, can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please post what you have already tried. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read about [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
import re
string1="stack-{data1}-XYZ-ABC-DEF-{data2}-DAB24-GOOD45-XYA-BYCS-{data3}-"
print (re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', string1))
```

It returns `['data1', 'data2', 'data3']`. Now you can compare element inside the list.

More simpler way would be just

```
string1[string1.find("{") +1: string1.find("}")]
```

It finds the first string between first brackets. But you get the idea.

**Edit** 
Modified answer based on Miraj50 comment. 
 Thanks

Comment: You can even remove the braces and collect only the words between the braces by using parentheses `re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', string1)`

Comment: AverageJoe9000  and Miraj50 Thank you so much it was of great help.